# how to extend the twitter message size to more than 140 characters

Tags: twitter

I am using a plugin to post my content in twitter, message size is more than 140 characters, so it is displaying a message that "Oops! Your tweet was over 140 characters", how can i increase this size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched better, i found a few links like "http://longertweets.com/" that will provide this option, but i have not implemented this yet.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. Twitter enforces this limit, so you can't tweet a message longer than 140 characters.